# Proof of equivalent metrics

Tags: general-topology

> [image]

Could someone explain how the inclusion $$\{ x \in X : d_2 < c_1 \epsilon \} \subset \{ x \in X : d_1 < \epsilon\}$$

possible?

I know that $\{ x \in X : d_1 < \epsilon\}$ is open, so there is another ball inside this one, but why necessary do we know it is under $d_2$? Is it because it is in $X$? Or am I asking an rhetorical question?

Comment: If $d_2(x,a) < c_1\epsilon$, then $$d_1(x,a) \leq \frac{1}{c_1}d_2(x,a) < \epsilon$$

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan, okay, so we are using the theorem, to prove the theorem??? Huh?

Comment: @Antoine, why are we allow to use the theorem we are trying to prove?

Comment: By the way: There is a typo in the second line of the quoted proof. It should read $a\in U$ instead of $a\in X$.

Comment: Actually why is $U$ open in $(X,d_2)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your goal is to prove that for all $a\in U$, there is an open $d_2$-ball around $a$ that lies in $U$.

By the hypothesis, it is true for a $d_1$-ball, since $U$ is open in $(X,d_1)$. Let this ball be $\{x\in X : d_1(x,a) < \epsilon\}$. Now by the assumption
$$c_1d_1(x,y) \leq d_2(x,y) \leq c_2d_1(x,y)$$
you have that $d_2(x,y) < c_1\epsilon \Rightarrow c_1d_1(x,a) < c_1\epsilon \Rightarrow d_1(x,y) < \epsilon$ since $c_1$ is positive.
Hence the ball $\{x \in X : d_2(x,a) < c_1\epsilon\}$ is included in $\{x\in X: d_1(x,a)<\epsilon\}$ hence in $U$, and $U$ is open in $(X,d_2)$.

Is it clearer?

Comment: Where did you get the assumption from? That is my concern. It would seem to me the assumption *is* the theorem.

Comment: Well yes, in the proof of a theorem you are allowed to (and in most cases, you *have* to) use the assumptions of the statement in order to prove the conclusion.

Comment: And that is not circular logic??

Comment: The theorem is of the form $A\Rightarrow B$, right? A proof of this statement has to prove $B$, assuming $A$. This is how logic works. How would you prove the statement "$\forall n\geq 3, x^n+y^n = z^n$ has no non-trivial integer solution" without using the fact that $n\geq 3$? (Hint: this is false for $n\leq 2$).

Comment: The important thing is that now you get it!

Comment: Symmetrically, the theorem could be written that $d_1$ is contained in $d_2$ right? For some other constants $b_1, b_2 > 0$

Comment: Yes, it is an easy exercise that the relation of being "topologically equivalent metrics" is indeed an equivalence relation. Your last comment says that this relation is symmetric. (Please consider accepting my answer or posting one yourself, in order to close this question)

Comment: A ball with $d_2 < c_2 \epsilon$ also works right? Since $(1/c_2) d_2 < c_2/c_2 d_1  < \epsilon$

Comment: No, if $d_2(x,a)<c_2\epsilon$, then all you can tell is that $d_1(x,a) < \frac{c_2}{c_1}\epsilon$, and $c_2$ is greater than $c_1$ if the two distances are not identical, hence this says nothing. We can go to the chat if you want, to avoid this lengthy comment-discussion.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12208/discussion-between-antoine-and-sidht)